# Plane passing through 2 points, parallel to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am given two points P and Q and a vector $\vec v$ in $R^3$. I want to find the plane that goes through P and Q and is parallel to v. So I made a vector PQ, but how can I make that into plane parallel to $\vec v$?

Comment: Check this [Describing a plane with a point and two vectors lying on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_with_a_point_and_two_vectors_lying_on_it)

Answer (score 1):

Generate a second $\vec{PQ}$ vector from P and Q. Take the cross product $\vec{PQ} \times \vec{v}$. Call it $\vec{N}$, since it is a normal vector to the plane. This is because both $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{v}$ are parallel to the plane.

Note that a plane is a collection of vectors which are perpendicular to a normal and which passes through a point. So we want any vector: $\vec{s} = \langle x-P_x, y-P_y, z-P_z\rangle$ to be perpendicular to n.

What does it mean for two vectors to be perpendicular? Their dot product is zero. So...

$\vec{N} \cdot \vec{s} =$

$N_x(x-P_x) + N_y(y-P_y) + N_z(z-P_z) = 0$

Comment: P and Q are points in the plane and so the vector generated by PQ is in the plane, or at least parallel to it.

Comment: There is no such thing as $P \times Q$. The vector PQ cross v is perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: Sorry. Writing from my tablet so not everything is coming out properly.

Answer (score 0):

take $\vec{x}=\vec{OP}+s\vec{QP}+t\vec{v}$ where $s$ and $t$ are real numbers